# Is the zero function a differentiable, continuous and polynomial function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, continuity

For $f(x): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

1. Differentiable, as the derivative will always be 0
2. Continuous, as it is just a horizontal line with no breaks
3. Polynomial, as it can be written as $f(x) = 0 = (1x^n - 1x^n)$

Would any of my reasoning be wrong?

Comment: It´s all correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Correct, $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{0}{x-a} = 0$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$

(2) This is not a mathematical reasoning, but rather an intuition why the statement is true. Here's a mathematical proof:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta =$ "your favorite non-zero positive number". Then, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x-a| < \delta$, we have $0 = |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$. Hence $f$ is continuous on its domain.

(3) Correct: Other examples:

$0 = 0x^0, 0 = 0x, \dots$

Comment: Nitpick: For many authors, $0x^0$ is not defined at $x=0.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: For **many** authors, it is, contrary to your claim. See the standard form of the Taylor series, the binomial theorem, Elementary Function Arithmetic, ... Defining $x^0 = 1$ for real $s$ is perfectly in line with the elegant viewpoint that **natural** exponents correspond to **iterates** of multiplication.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro In the context of polynomials, which is what (3) is concerned with, $x^0$ is definitely $1$, hence $0x^0=0$ for every $x$ in the underlying field $K$. How would one write every polynomial $P(x)$ in $K[x]$ as $$P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$$ otherwise? And the associated polynomial function $f_P:K\to K$ is indeed defined by $$f_P(t)=\sum_{i=0}^na_it^i=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots+a_nt^n$$ for every $t$ in $K$, it seems to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in all three statements.

The function $f(x)=0$ is a special case of $f(x)=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

The same statements are true for $f(x)=c$ for any constant $c$ which are considered as polynomials of degree $0$

$1)$   Differentiable, as the derivative will always be $ 0$

$2)$ Continuous, as it is just a horizontal line with no breaks

$3)$ Polynomial, as it can be written as$ f(x) =  c+ 0x+0x^2 $

Comment: **Every** constant function is both continuous and differentiable.

Comment: Correct, the constant functions are just horizontal lines.